# stack overflow error

Tags: php, javascript

i just got my first ever stack overflow when I ran this script:

```
var hlat = 0.00;
var hlong = 0.00;
var mapdiv = document.getElementById('map');
var map_url = base_url + 'ajax/getPropMap';
var id_url = base_url + 'hotels/gethotel_id';
var id=0;
var map = null;
// apply gmaps to product map div

$(function(){
    $.get(id_url, {id: segment}, getMapDetails);
});

function getMapDetails(data){
    $.getJSON(map_url, {id:data}, addToProdMap);
}

function getMapDetails(data){
    addProdMap(data);
}

function addProdMap(data){
    hlat = data.latitude;
    hlong = data.longitude;

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapdiv, {
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(hlat, hlong),
            zoom : 13,
            mapTypeId : 'hybrid'
    });

    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(hlat, hlong);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        clickable : true,
        map: map,
        icon : 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        position : coords
    })
}
```

How do I deal with this? Firefox closes and IE displays the stack overflow error

Comment: Do you have some debugging results from IE? And what exactly does this have to do with PHP? ;)

Comment: Did you intentionally create two functions with the name getMapDetails?

Comment: @Franz: i am using the Kohana PHP framework as my backend here, and up to the top is the call to the controller...or does that not count this as having a PHP tag? no debuggin results from IE

Comment: ugh...this is a really shocking revelation and I really feel so dumb about this one...I just solved it thanks to Jacob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two functions of the same name: `getMapDetails`

Comment: that duplicate function name is the problem, the line you higlight is a function that triggers on page load, trying to retrieve a session variable from the server...so, I guess I'll choose your answer

Comment: Yes, if you comment that line out I don't think you will get the error (because that is when the function in question actually gets invoked).  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Upgrade to the latest Firefox

Step 2: Install Firebug

Step 3: After those two steps Firefox should no longer crash when you try and run that script.  If it does, try wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch and log the exception which gets caught.  If it doesn't crash, the exception should just be logged to your Firebug console as normal (assuming you have it turned on).

Step 4: Now that you've actually got an exception you can look at, just follow the stacktrace to see what line in particular is causing the problem.

Hope that works (but if not comment back).